# How do I change continent in Planetside 2?

Tags: planetside-2

How can I change the continent I'm on in Planetside 2?

Sometimes I can deploy to another continent, but other times there's not way of switching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was a bit more obvious after I respawned at my warpgate. Just re-spawn at your warpgate (type `/suicide` in the chat box) and you'll see two computers where you can change continents by pressing E:

[image: Planetside 2 change continents]

Answer (score 1):

As you implied in your original question, you can also "instant action" between continents.  On map view, change continents with the buttons up the very top left.  Then the deploy buttons (instant action buttons) will drop you into that territory on that continent, by dropping you from a drop pod.  The buttons on the bottom left indicating hot spots are also continent-independent so they can also take you to different continents.

The downside to this is that there is a timer between successive uses of instant action so you can't do it more than once every 10 minutes? or so.